# jxbrowser - disable ssl/tls certificate check

Tags: java, ssl, javafx, chromium-embedded, jxbrowser

I need to disable HTTP chertificate check in fxBrowser via JAVAfx, Now I'm calling it as

```
AnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
BrowserView _nodevW;

Browser _browser =  Engine.newInstance(
    EngineOptions.newBuilder(
        OFF_SCREEN
    ).addSwitch("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    .chromiumDir(
        "C:\\TMP\\JX"
    ).enableProprietaryFeature(
        ProprietaryFeature.H_264
    ).enableIncognito().build()
    
    _browser = engine.newBrowser();
    _nodevW = BrowserView.newInstance(_browser);
    _browser.navigation().loadUrl(url);
    
    
    anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(_nodevW);
```

It works perfectly for plain http and https with valid certificates, but fails for self-signed or certificate deemed invalid with `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

How do I tell the browser to ignore invalid certificates (I can't install the certificates on client machines, but I can ignore them)

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the invalid SSL certificates and continue loading an HTTPS web page using the following approach:

```
Network network = engine.network();
network.set(VerifyCertificateCallback.class, (params) -> 
        VerifyCertificateCallback.Response.valid());
```

You can read more about this API in [documentation](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/network.html#certificate-verification).